# Cannot GET/file1

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

Please kindly consider that I'm new to node js. I tried to do url routing with node js by allowing the url link localhost:8080/file1 and localhost:8080/file2 to direct to the fies in 'views' folder of the root directory and if such a file is not found user is directed to 404.html page. But is keeps saying Cannot GET/ for any url parameter is types on the address bar.

Can someone kindly show me the problem here. My main js file is as follows.

```
var express= require('express');
var app = express();
var fs  = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

app.use('/mycssfiles',express.static(__dirname+'/css'));

app.get("/",function(request,response){

    response.sendFile('home.html',{root:__dirname});
});

app.get("/^(.+)",function(request,response){



    try{
      if(fs.statSync(path.join(__dirname,'views',request.params[0]+'.html'))){

        response.sendFile(request.params[0]+'.html',{root:path.join(__dirname,'views')});
      }
    }
    catch(error){
        response.sendFile('404.html',{root:path.join(__dirname,'views')});
    }

});

app.listen(8080, function() {

console.log('server is up');
});
```

Comment: `app.get("/^(.+)"` wont work. Either use a literal RegEx, meaning `/\/^(.+)/` or use `/:page` and then `request.params.page`

Comment: `express.static` can handle the `.html` files too which it looks like your trying to implement. but to answer, you need an else which throws

Comment: @LucaKiebel thanks a lot using /^(.+)/ worked.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yeah thanks for pointing out